# MVC lookup tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I have in my MVC app a tax rate table. It has no foreign key relationships to any other tables.

Then I have a model class Invoice:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace VectorCheck.Models
{
    public class Invoice : IEntity, IValidatableObject
    {
        public virtual int InvoiceId { get; set; }

        public decimal PayableAmount
        {
           get
           {
               var taxrates = new Repository<TaxRate>();
               var taxrate = taxrates.Where(.....some condition.....);
               return AQuantityOfMoney * taxrate;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

So the problem I see here is I need to instantiate my datasource inside my model. Not good?

Can anybody tell me a better way to approach solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the `PayableAmount` property into a method and pass the repository as parameter:

```
public decimal GetPayableAmount(ITaxRateCalculator taxrates)
{
    var taxrate = taxrates.Where(.....some condition.....);
    return AQuantityOfMoney * taxrate;
}
```